# How do I reply directly to answers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Forgive my ignorance, but I can't seem to figure out how to make comment replies to those who have answered my questions on Stack Overflow. One user told me: "You have a little 'add comment' link beneath each answer", but I do not. I have `link`|`flag` buttons, but I don't see how the permalink or flag buttons allow be to comment on someone's answer. I'm probably missing something blatantly obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation. Try answering some questions so that SO trusts you a little bit more.

Comment: I trust you, OP. How did you ever end up with 0 rep?

Comment: you need a certain amount of points (50) to do comments. see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You cannot see the "add comment" because you need 50 reputation to do it. Please have a look at the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) for further detail.

Comment: This is a question for Meta Stack Overflow. In fact, there’s already a couple of questions on Meta about this issue — in summary, you need more reputation. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: You should be able to comment on your own questions, answers, and answers to your questions regardless of reputation. If it's not showing up for the asker, then that is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

The account from which you posted this question only has this *one* question on Stack Overflow (at this time). You can comment on answers for questions that have been posted by you. But since account creation is so easy on Stack Overflow, you're likely creating new accounts each time you visit the website without realising it.

Create a *real* account, and use that. You'll find participation much smoother. Furthermore, you'll be able to associate your real account with an account on Meta, which means you'll own *this* question too. Right now you don't, since it was automatically migrated but you don't have an associated account here.

Comment: this makes no sense

Comment: @user2234181 Why not?